# Unable to find "SharePoint Drafts" folder

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, draft

I am using SharePoint as a repository for version control of the documents.But when I check out a file, I am unable to see where does it go. I am using Windows 7 - 32 bit. I have checked its "Documents" folder as well but there's nothing like "SharePoint Drafts". Where can I find that?

Comment: What do you mean by where can I find that? What are you trying to find? When you checkout and if minor/major versions are turned on (from Library settings) than a minor version is created where you can change, and once done check-in to make it a major version.. All versions are stored in SharePoint's internal database, even the file itself.. You will not find physical files for each version

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just disabled Internet Explorer's security settings. And then checked out a file and a folder "SharePoint Drafts" created in my "Documents" folder i.e. here :

C:\Users\username\Documents\SharePoint Drafts

Here are all those files which are checked out by me.

Thanks for all for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing what Arsalan mentioned, there is no local (=you your hard drive) copy made when you check out a document. Checking out just marks the document as read-only for anyone else except you, and after you modify the document and check it in, changes are stored to SharePoint database, and document is released for others to check out and edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout and if minor/major versions are turned on (from Library settings) than a minor version is created where you can change, and once done check-in to make it a major version.. All versions are stored in SharePoint's internal database, even the file itself.. You will not find physical files for each version

Comment: I want to checkout a file, replace it with my local copy and then check in. My colleague can see the checked out files in SharePoint Drafts folder.